# I cannot visualize total data well on ggplot2 histogram in R language

Tags: r

I'm an amateur in R language. I have a total data of something in Dataframe.

```
data <- data.frame(coun =country, tot = total, yr=year)
data <- data[ with(data, order(tot,decreasing = TRUE)),]
rownames(data) <- NULL
head(data)
```

Output of this chunk.[image]

There is no problem for now. But:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=tot))+ geom_histogram()
```

When I typed something to visualize the data, I came across a graph like this:

Output of above code.[image]

The data from the tot column will be visualized in this graph, which will contain nation names on the x-axis.

What should I do, guys?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should ask a specific question that explains what you want to do.  Are you trying to count the number of values of `tot`? Or to plot `tot` for each country? Or what?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Post has been edited thanks to you. I want to visualize the data of tot column and this graph will include country names on the x-axis.

Comment: You seem to be describing a bar chart, not a histogram. Maybe `ggplot(data = data, aes(x=count, y=tot))+ geom_col()` is more what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A histogram is used to visualise the distribution of a continuous variable, but you're trying to plot count data stratified by a categorical variable - for this, you use a bar chart.

Because your data is already in summary form, you use `geom_bar()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(coun = c("UNITED STATES", "CHINA (MAINLAND)", "USSR", "JAPAN", "SINGAPORE", "RUSSIAN FEDERATION"),
           tot = c(3139676, 2950105, 1144547, 876384, 742819, 691644))

ggplot(data, aes(coun, tot)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

PS: **please don't post your data as screenshots** - I had to manually recreate your dataset. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that your next questions are more likely to get help.